# Performing Automation Testing for both Web and Desktop Applications at the same time

Tags: angularjs, automation

I am performing an automation testing, and I have two applications. one is web application and the other is desktop application (WPF). They work together and one needs the other. To perform task on the desktop application the task should be finished first by the web application. I can do automation testing for the web application using Selenium or Protractor. At the same time I I can do automation testing for the Desktop application using Winium. But what I want is to perform automation for both sequentially. Is there any solution some one can provide me?

For your information my web application is developed using Angular JS.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Everything is possible, however it's unclear exactly what you are expecting as an answer here.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how I have configured my tests. I choose C# as the programming language. Selenium has .Net bindings so for UI interaction I use Selenium (C#). For Desktop App I am using FlaUI / (TestStack.White). My tests are written in SpecFlow (BDD's implementation in .Net). So that way I am able to test all of my apps under one umbrella and still use all of the open source technology for testing.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use following Tools :** By using following tools you can interact with both Desktop and Web Component in a Single Test

- **Tosca** :

It also supports Desktop and Web Automation. It's **Community edition** is **FREE**.

[Refer Tosca](https://www.tricentis.com/products/automate-continuous-testing-tosca/)

- **Ranorex**

It supports Desktop, Web And Mobile as well. It is paid tool.

[Refer Ranorex](https://www.ranorex.com/)

- **TestComplete**

It is an automated testing tool that lets you create, manage and run tests for any Windows, Web or Rich Client software. It makes it easy for anyone to create automated tests. And automated tests run faster, increase test coverage and lower costs. It is paid tool.

[Refer Test Complete](https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/)

Comment: Thank you so much bro. You saved my day

Comment: @muller : Could you please accept the answer by clicking on "tick" symbol